# Order statistics in limit

Tags: probability-theory, order-statistics

Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots$ denote a sequence of $iid$ continuous random variables with some distribution $F(\cdot)$. Condition on $X_1 = x$ and fix $\rho\in (0,1)$. Define
$$
A_n = \{X_1 \text{ is among the least $\rho n$ random variables in $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$}   \}.
$$
I am interested in $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n)$. My guess is that it converges to one if $x \leq c$ where $F(c) = \rho$, and zero otherwise.

Comment: If $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are i.i.d., what does it mean to "fix $X_1 = x$"? Do you mean that the probabilities you consider are conditional probabilities given $\{X_1 = x\}$.

Comment: Yes. I guess that is clear. They are independent, so that does not affect other r.v.s. I changed it, though.

Comment: Do you mean $F(x) \leq \rho$? Because $P(A_n)$ should not depend on the distribution $F$, while the range of $X_1$ does depend on $F$. So you need a way to put them on the same ground.

Comment: Thanks, I correct my statement accordingly.

Comment: How does the Kolmogorov 0-1 Law apply here? I don't see a tail event anywhere.

Comment: Correct, it does not. I removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, consider the case where $X_k$'s are i.i.d. and uniformly distributed between $[0, 1]$. For each $n \geq 1$, let $X_{n,1} \leq \cdots \leq X_{n,n}$ denote the $n$-th order statistic. Then it is not hard to show that, for each $\rho \in (0, 1)$,

$$ \sqrt{n} ( X_{n,\lfloor n\rho\rfloor} - \rho ) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{\text{law}} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_{\rho}^2) $$

for some $\sigma_{\rho} > 0$ which we can explicitly figure out. Then

$$ P(A_n)
= P(X_{n,\lfloor n\rho\rfloor} > x)
= P\big(\sqrt{n}(X_{n,\lfloor n\rho\rfloor} - \rho) > \sqrt{n}(x - \rho)\big), $$

and so, it follows that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n) = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $x > \rho$}; \\
\frac{1}{2}, & \text{if $x = \rho$}; \\
1, & \text{if $x < \rho$};
\end{cases} $$

Comment: Thanks. This problem is related to Central Order Statistics and the first person study this problem is Smirnov. The paper can be found here: [link](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=tm&paperid=1025&option_lang=eng), it is in Russian though.